# How to resolve environment via url path variable?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have some rest web application with endpoint:
`/some/endpoint` in SomeController

I want my application to resolve environment config via path variable. This config should define DB to which should my application connect.

E.g.: `/db1/some/endpoint` means that application should use `db1` config. This config will be used to setup context with SCOPE_REQUEST.

How should I do this without changes to SomeController?

UPDATED:
Sure, I can do it directly in Controller with request mapping like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{config}/my/super/endpoint"})
public void mySuperEndpoint(@PathVariable("config") String config) {
    myConfig.use(config);

    ...

}
```

but what if I have 10 endpoints? or 10 controllers? and all of them need same logic with config.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Please share what you have already tried. Also have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users#182380

Comment: I tried to find find tips and read manuals, but could not find any good solution. Perhaps there is no such one. 

I am not an expert in spring-boot so I will be happy to any suggestions.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without refactoring the code. How about different application instance with another profile?

Comment: I want to be able to dynamically add profiles on the same application instance.

Comment: Im now looking on HandlerInterceptor, this could be solution but there are two problems:
1) manual url parsing
2) i can't modify url after processing with handler, so my controller should know about full url mapping

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that I don't understand completely your question. Usually, environments resolved in spring boot by profiles (like application-db1.yml, application-prod.yml, etc... )

This can be achieved by either a different application instance with db1 profile or handling the path variable programmatically in the controller(Consider this as a Resource as per REST terms).